# C# Post JSON Array to Facebook API in batches of 2100

Tags: c#, json

I have a requirement to post a JSON array to Facebook in batches of 2100. Being very new to C# I'm not sure on the best way to approach this.

Firstly I'm getting the data from a SQL database and holding in a jsonString variable:

```
public void getOfflineData()
{
    var dataSet = new DataSet();

    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString);
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 1200;
    try
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = sqlCommand };

        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        jsonString = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString(); //jsonString = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Stock"].ToString();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
        sqlConn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Next I make a connection to the Facebook API and do a POST:

```
public void postOfflineData(string adsmanagementtoken, string versionno, string offlineeventsetid, string uriauth)
{
    RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer();

    var client = new RestClient(uriauth + "{versionno}/{offlineconversiondatasetid}/events");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    request.AddUrlSegment("versionno", versionno);
    request.AddUrlSegment("offlineconversiondatasetid", offlineeventsetid);
    request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + adsmanagementtoken + "");
    request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "upload_tag= Offline Conversion Data" + "&data=[" + jsonString + "]",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    if (response.Content.ToString().Contains("id") == false)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Invalid call");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "ERROR", ex.Message, null, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        FacebookAttributes returnData = deserial.Deserialize<FacebookAttributes>(response);

        if (returnData.id != null)
        {
            offline_event_set_id = returnData.id;
        }
    }
}
```

The error message I receive is:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#105) The number of parameters exceeded the 
maximum for this 
operation","type":"OAuthException","code":105,"error_data":"Facebook 
Offline Events API supports maximum uploads of 2100 events at a time. 
Please reduce the number of events per API call and try 
again.","fbtrace_id":"B3xJi2SYqMs"}}
```

I have a feeling I need to combine the above two into a single class(?) then load the jsonString and do the post using a WHILE loop. Not sure if this is the most efficient way as I'm sure there a better solutions out there. Can anyone advise? Thanks

Comment: A rather ad-hoc approach, but deseralize into objects(collections). Break into chunks of 2100, loop through the chunks and post. ?

Comment: Thanks Tez, I'll give this a go